# How do i access custom my domain in apex

Tags: custom, mydomain

I want to access custom my domain in apex class. For e.g https://checkDB.my.salesforce.com is the domain. Is there any method to access this domain in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following statement will give you your base URL.

```
System.debug('URL ' + System.Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() );
```

> Update: Added replacement logic for VF.

```
   public Pagereference getData(){
        String str=  System.Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() ; 
        System.debug('removing -- : ' + str.substringBeforeLast('--') );
        str = str.substringBeforeLast('--') + '.my.salesforce.com';
        System.debug('str: ' + str);
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: It returns https://checkDB--c.tes.visual.force.com

Comment: not exactly same domain name https://checkDB.my.salesforce.com

Comment: Yes it does returns same. Where you're testing the same?  I tried this in Anonymous window. (you can try the same).

Comment: True, while running on Anonymous window getting https:// checkDB.my.salesforce.com.                                                                             I have created page and class, writing this line in method. 
<apex:commandButton action="{!getData}" value="Submit" >
Class
public Pagereference getData(){System.debug('URL ' + System.Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() ); }  and Preview the page

Comment: Yes, I checked. Well, in this case you can tweak the URL. I mean just replace the : "--c.ap5.visual.force." i.e.  after DOUBLE DASH to DOT COM, you need to replace DOT_MY_SALESFORCE.

Comment: @s.cloud updated answer.Please check.

Comment: Please be aware that your method for parsing a Visualforce base URL should be built to remain compatible with the following upcoming Critical Update: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_instance_names_removed.htm#rn_vf_instance_names_removed so for example `mydomain--c.na5.visual.force.com` would become `mydomain--c.visualforce.com`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesT for the update! However, I guess, current logic will work with this change. As I did take front part of --(double dash). so domain changes will be replaced with "dot_salesforce_com", as expected.